# Command line to list DNS servers used by my system

Tags: command-line, dns

Is there a command to list DNS servers used by my system?

I tried

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf 
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.0.1
$ cat /etc/network/interfaces 
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

But it doesn't list any servers. If I go to "Network Manager GUI Tool", in the Wireless section it lists "DNS 192.168.1.1 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4".

Can I get the same information from the command line?

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Comment: What are you trying to find?  the DNS servers being used by your system?  or are you trying to do a DNS lookup?

Comment: The former @LordofTime

Comment: @LordofTime DNS servers being used by my system

Comment: you are using 127.0.0.1.  are you *running* a DNS server?

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/28941/38647 for a non-Ubuntu version of this question

Answer (score 365, accepted):

resolv.conf isn't really used anymore, unless you implement it yourself.  The network manager does it now.  I created an alias to list the DNS servers on my system, as I sometimes switch from OpenDNS to Google's open DNS.

**Ubuntu >= 15**

```
nmcli device show <interfacename> | grep IP4.DNS
```

**Ubuntu <= 14**

```
nmcli dev list iface <interfacename> | grep IP4
```

In my case, `<interfacename>` is `eth0`, which is common, but not always the case. You can see your interfaces with

```
nmcli device status
```

See if this is what you want.

EDIT:

I think resolv.conf is actually used indirectly, because the network manager creates the server that listens on 127.0.0.1, but I was told that this is an implementation detail that should not be counted on.  I think that if you enter DNS addresses before this entry, they might get used, but I'm not sure exactly how this works.  I think it's best to use the network manager in most cases, when possible.

Comment: thanks, yes that seems to be working, ubuntu networking seems to be confusing, so I can set dns servers in resolve.conf/base or in /etc/network/interfaces or in network manager, is there a definitive guide for ubuntu networking?

Comment: If you use the GUI, then the best place to set it is by creating profiles in the Network Connections Dialog.  I duplicated the default, then edited the duplicate to make the changes I wanted, keeping the default to make sure I always had a working profile.  Then, it's easy to switch profiles.  I don't know how to do this without the GUI, but there is a user "James Henstridge" who is very knowledgeable on Ubuntu's networking; you might try searching askubuntu for his information.  He told me about the command I gave you in [this post](http://askubuntu.com/q/129089/39753).

Comment: http://www.stgraber.org/2012/02/24/dns-in-ubuntu-12-04/ is a nice article abount DNS resolution in ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Nice link - a lot of good information there to digest.

Comment: That didn't work for me, but nm-tool does.

Comment: Are you using 12.04, the version specified?  Did you substitute something like "eth0" for <interfacename>? (My original post actually made it clearer, but someone changed it, and I added the note below).  It still works for me, every day.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. With a `vpnc` VPN connected, `nmcli dev list iface eth0` shows the original DNS server, but the VPN's DNS server is not listed, even if I use `tun0` for `<interfacename>`. So it might work some of the time but is not reliable in every case.

Comment: @MartyFried Your answer seems to be stuck at 42 votes :)

Comment: It would be great to figure out a way to do this without network-manager, which would be preferable for servers.  Actually, as suggested by one of the below answers, it looks like `cat /etc/resolv.conf` does exactly that.  I have the DNS servers configured in `/etc/network/interfaces` and they do land in `resolv.conf` as expected.

Comment: Seems `nmcli` has changed its syntax. Command `nmcli dev list iface` no longer works. I have written an answer to similar question for Ubuntu 14.04 and later:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/637893/how-to-know-what-dns-am-i-using-in-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: It still works for me using 14.04.  You do need to add the device at the end, of course (ie, eth0, eth1, or whatever device you are using).

Comment: By the way, `nmcli dev show` doesn't work for 14.04.  That's the version I have, so I can't speak for future versions

Comment: I'm using 15.04 and 'nmcli dev show |grep DNS' works for me instead.

Comment: ffs. i think you just made me install Gnome on my server.

Comment: 16.04: The program 'nmcli' is currently not installed.

Comment: @vcardillo:  the original question stated: "I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS". It's been 5 years since I posted my answer.  Nothing lasts forever.

Comment: I would like to warn readers that the information provided by nmcli and nm-tool might not be correct. In testing my router setup, I changed the DHCP server to configure a DNS. On my client (linux mint 17.3) I did `sudo dhclient -r; sudo dhclient` to renew IP configuration. At this point both commands I mentioned showed the old DNS, not the new one. `cat /etc/resolv.conf` did work for me, but according to op it did not work for him. The only reliable way to figure out which DNS is used appears to be to a lookup with for example dig, but I doubt dig will show you all configured DNS.

Comment: On Ubuntu 20, running `nmcli device show eth0` shows `Error: Could not create NMClient object: Could not connect: No such file or directory.` (my network interface is `eth0`)

Comment: Doesn't work, even on on an 22.04 Server.

Comment: Works on Kubuntu 22.04, with `nmcli device status` first to discover the device name

Comment: nmcli will not work on any Ubuntu SERVER version. Ubuntu Server uses netplan. These instructions are only for Ubuntu Desktop out of the box. For Ubuntu server you need to  `cat /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml`, or check with `systemd-resolve --status` at the very end of the output. OP should update their post to say this is only for ubuntu desktop.

Comment: @AlexPotapenko I was about to post the same thing about 20.04. Also, once we get to "nmcli dev show <iface>" then I'm guessing the IP4 address after "IP4.DNS[1]" is the DNS I'm using?

Comment: My only problem is that I think what comes after "IP4.DNS[1]" is the same as after "IP4.GATEWAY" (1st 3 bytes are my LAN/intranet address, and last byte is 1), so I don't think it's the true DNS, which I guess my computer lets the the modem or router or something determine.

Comment: That seems like a whole different problem/potential question, though.

Answer (score 216):

In Ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04 you can use `systemd-resolve --status`.
In newer versions use `resolvectl status`.

Comment: NB if you cat /etc/resolv.conf it even says this

Comment: On 21.04 it says `sd_bus_open_system: No such file or directory`

Comment: IMO this should be the accepted answer. Also, it's worth pointing out that `systemd-resolve mydomain.com` outputs which DNS server exactly is being queried (very useful if e.g. you have set up a VPN and so on).

Comment: This is not a full answer as it does not explain what the command returns.

Comment: Doesn't work, even on on an 22.04 Server.

Comment: Doesn't work on the 22.04 Desktop edition either: command not found (which was kind-of expected really)

Comment: this has been replaced by `resolvectl status`.  upvote https://askubuntu.com/a/1399661/25918

Comment: This output is TMI... I use this instead `systemd-resolve --status --no-pager | grep "DNS Servers" -A 2`

Comment: In my Ubuntu, I just settled on `resolvectl --no-pager --protocol=dns status | sed -n 's/ *DNS Servers: *//p'`

Answer (score 88):

This is valid for Ubuntu 13.10 and earlier. For Ubuntu 14.04 and above, see [Koala Yeung's answer to: How to know what DNS am I using in Ubuntu from 14.04 onwards](https://askubuntu.com/a/637894/117103)

---

Use

```
nm-tool
```

You will get an output similar to

```
NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: eth0  [Wired connection 1] -------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            e1000e
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        00:11:22:33:44:55

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes
    Speed:           1000 Mb/s

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         on

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         10.21.6.13
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
    Gateway:         10.21.6.1

    DNS:             10.22.5.133
    DNS:             10.22.5.3
```

Or to see just the DNS do

```
nm-tool | grep DNS
```

Comment: just wanted to add-up, going to `nm-applet`'s connection information menu will also work :)

Comment: +1 this also works, as does nm-cli as answered by @Marty Fried

Comment: Yes, same info, but nmcli is easier to parse if you want to extract it out for a different presentation, such as conky, or simply a summary like my grep.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. With a `vpnc` VPN connected, `nm-tool` shows the original DNS server, but the VPN's DNS server is not listed. So it might work some of the time but is not reliable in every case.

Comment: works great on lubuntu 14.04 as well. thanks

Comment: nm-tool is not found on 15.10

Comment: this installs a *!@#$load* of packages. Is there a light weight cli tool?

Comment: yeah this doesn't work anymore... no `nm-tool` in 16.x either. `nmcli` (in Marty Fried's answer) is the way to go

Comment: Doesn't work, even on on an 22.04 Server.

Comment: Again a case of giving an answer for Ubuntu Desktop. NetworkManager, nmtui, nmcli commands only work on Ubuntu Desktop out of the box. Ubuntu server uses netplan. This wont work on Ubuntu server.

Answer (score 78):

The two top-scoring answers, `nmcli dev list iface <interfacename> | grep IP4` and `nm-tool` both assume that network-manager is in control. Which it is - on desktop machines most of the time at least. But the fuller answer is that sometimes network-manager is not in control. E.g. `vpnc` messes with `/etc/resolv.conf` directly.

So: First check if 127.0.0.1/localhost is used. This could be done with `dig`:

```
> dig something.unknown  | grep SERVER:
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
```

Now you know that we *are* using localhost. Go ahead with one of the popular answers. I like:

```
> nm-tool | grep DNS:
    DNS:             8.8.8.8
```

But if 127.0.0.1/localhost is *not* used, then `nm-tool`'s and `nmcli`'s output will be misleading:

```
> dig something.unknown  | grep SERVER:
;; SERVER: 172.22.216.251#53(172.22.216.251)
> nm-tool | grep DNS:
    DNS:             8.8.8.8
```

Here, `dig` is correct and `nm-tool`'s information is misleading. In reality addresses local to the environment I've VPN-ed into are resolved correctly. All of which Google's DNS `8.8.8.8` *doesn't* know about.

This is because after connecting to a VPN with `vpnc`, it puts a line in `/etc/resolv.conf` so it looks like:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 1.2.3.4
nameserver 127.0.0.1
search MyDomain
```

Comment: Thank you. Some of us out here do not use NM and that is good for the community.

Comment: Just for completion, the `dig` utility can be easily installed with `apt install dnsutils`.

Comment: though you just need dig | grep SERVER: ... dig will give you the root DNS if you pass no address

Answer (score 39):

`cat /etc/resolv.conf` should show your DNS servers.

You may not modify the `resolv.conf` directly with Ubuntu 12.04. If you need to change them though, you can add new DNS servers in your 
`/etc/network/interfaces` file by adding the following:

```
 dns-nameservers x.x.x.x x.x.x.x
```

where `x` is the DNS servers you wish to use.

If I were you, I would uninstall `network-manager`. In my opinion it's a pile of crap.

You can accomplish everything you need to do manually without worrying about changing your settings, especially if you have multiple NICs on the computer.

Comment: Do I have to restart nm after doing the dns change?

Comment: --Thanks. This is great. It works even without that network-manager business.

Comment: "cat /etc/resolv.conf should show your DNS servers". It doesn't.

Answer (score 16):

In Ubuntu 20.04, if your `resolve.conf` points to loopback:

```
$ sudo cat /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf
nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
```

and:

```
$ ss -plnt | grep ':53'
LISTEN   0        4096            127.0.0.53%lo:53               0.0.0.0:*
```

you can use `resolvectl` to show status for interfaces:

```
$ resolvectl status

Global
LLMNR setting: no                  
MulticastDNS setting: no                  
  DNSOverTLS setting: no                  
      DNSSEC setting: no                  
    DNSSEC supported: no                  
          DNSSEC NTA: 10.in-addr.arpa
....

Link 4 (wlo1)
      Current Scopes: DNS           
DefaultRoute setting: yes           
       LLMNR setting: yes           
MulticastDNS setting: no            
  DNSOverTLS setting: no            
      DNSSEC setting: no            
    DNSSEC supported: no            
  Current DNS Server: 10.128.128.128
         DNS Servers: 10.128.128.128
          DNS Domain: ~.
```

Comment: "resolvectl status" does the trick, even on 22.04. Also: why is this not the accepted / highest ranking answer? It's so far down the list that I got my server-specific (no nm* tools) shut down.

Answer (score 13):

nmcli version 0.9.10

You can use either of these commands:

```
nmcli -t -f IP4.DNS device show eth0
IP4.DNS[1]:192.168.1.1
IP4.DNS[2]:8.8.8.8

nmcli -t -f IP4.DNS connection show conn-name
IP4.DNS[1]:192.168.1.1
IP4.DNS[2]:8.8.8.8
```

Answer (score 5):

Amazing how many ways there are to do it. On an Ubuntu Server 18.04, if you don't want to install anything extra like `nm-tool`, then `systemd-resolve --status` will work out of the box for DNS information.

If you're interested getting not only your DNS servers, but also default gateway, IP address, network mask, etc, then `netplan ip leases eth0` will give you all that information in an easy-to-read form (assuming you're interested in the `eth0` interface).

Comment: Thank you, I didn't have NetworkManager and didn't want to install it, your answer was very helpful.

Answer (score 4):

Since Ubuntu 20.04, you can use `resolvectl` which has been already mentioned. But I would like to highlight the `dns` which is a little bit more clean compared to `status`, see

**resolvectl dns**

```
$ resolvectl dns
Global:
Link 2 (ens34): 8.8.8.8
Link 3 (docker0):
```

**resolvectl [status]**

```
$ resolvectl 
Global
       Protocols: -LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
resolv.conf mode: stub

Link 2 (ens34)
    Current Scopes: DNS
         Protocols: +DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
Current DNS Server: 8.8.8.8
       DNS Servers: 8.8.8.8
        DNS Domain: company.com

Link 3 (docker0)
Current Scopes: none
     Protocols: -DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
```

Answer (score 3):

In Ubuntu 15.10 you can get DNS

```
nmcli device show <interface name>
```

Answer (score 3):

On Ubuntu 20.04

```
systemd-resolve --status | grep -B 9 -A 6 "Current DNS Server"
```

gave me a clear result as to what DNS was in use for each adapter using DNS.

To reconfigure DNS

```
man systemd-resolved
```

reveals the DNS servers contacted are determined by global settings in `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf`.

Sudo edit that file and uncomment and set `DNS=` and `FallbackDNS=` to the IPv4 DNS servers you want.
For example, `DNS=8.8.8.8` and `FallbackDNS=8.8.4.4` would use [Google Public DNS](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/).
Restart the machine to apply the change.

@PLA, thank you for this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1079009) which led me down this path.

Answer (score 2):

On systems where `systemd-resolved` is NOT installed :

```bash
$ host -v something.unknown | awk -F "[ #]" '/Received /{print$5}' | uniq
192.168.1.1
```

On systems where `NetworkManager` is running :

```
$ ( nmcli -f IP4.DNS,IP6.DNS dev list || nmcli -f IP4.DNS,IP6.DNS dev show ) 2>/dev/null | awk '/DNS/{print$NF}'
192.168.1.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be managed by network manager. Have a look here http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man5/NetworkManager.conf.5.html

for a large explanation.

Or the short version it to look in

```
 /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

or

```
 <SYSCONFDIR>/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

Comment: but `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` doesn't have any dns servers listed in it

Comment: This is the correct location to edit as the Network Manager is in control.

Answer (score 0):

Many of the posts here have two problems:

1. They provide only an answer for Ubuntu Desktop systems that employ NetworkManger out of the box
2. Provide false information of checking `/etc/resolv.conf`

First of all, Stop checking or editing /etc/resolv.conf on current Ubuntu systems. Ubuntu is deeply embedded in systemd. This means ntp, hostnames, services, and DNS are being supported by systemd services. You will noticed that /etc/resolv.conf will only have one address `127.0.0.53` which is yourself, mainly talking to systemd dns services. Dont change this file, stop looking at it, stop messing with it.

## How to check Ubuntu Desktop DNS settings and status:

- As @iman pointed out You can check settings from nmcli:

```
ip -br a 
# Make note of interface name
nmcli -t -f IP4.DNS device show $interface_name
```

## How to check Ubuntu SERVER DNS settings and status:

- You can check settings from the netplan conf file

```
cat /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml
```

## How to check status of DNS on Ubuntu Desktop and Ubuntu Server:

- You can check status of DNS with this command

```
systemd-resolve --status --no-pager | grep "DNS Servers" -A 2
```

Note the above is only to list the number of dns servers if there are only two. If you want all of the DNS servers (a variable ammount) use this

```
systemd-resolve --status | awk '{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i~/^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$/) print $i }'
```