# Dnsmasq has changed the way it works in 12.10 - can someone point me to documentation or info on the changes

Tags: 12.10, dnsmasq

The way dnsmasq works with 12.10 has changed again, from 12.04. I have searched the Ubuntu documentation and Google for further info , without success.

Basically in 12.04 you could see the list of upstream DNS servers passed to dnsmasq in the file `/var/run/nm-dns-dnsmasq.conf`. This file in 12.10 is empty, and with all the reading I have done, it appears to be being managed by dbus. I just need to know where this information is being stored, as it is causing us an issue with VirtualBox, not correctly passing through the DHCP information.

I know I could switch this service off , with the switch for the network manager service, but I would rather understand how the new system functions, and correct the issue there.

Any pointers to how this works gratefully received.

Comment: I now have the answer to this, thanks to Stephane Graber:           In 12.10 dnsmasq and NetworkManager were changed to use dbus to
communicate instead of having to respawn dnsmasq for every change.

The result of that is that all the configuration is now passed over dbus
and there's no more configuration file used to provision dnsmasq.

You can query the current configuration with "nm-tool" or by looking at
your syslog where any dnsmasq configuration change is logged.

Comment: It's ok to put an answer to your own question and mark that answer as the solution, and we don't usually put solved in the title of the question here.

Answer (score 5):

NetworkManager talks with dnsmasq over dbus [now](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2091019&p=12390887#post12390887). This has one advantage: dnsmasq does not have to be restartet everytime something changes.

The big downside: You can't really see what's going on anymore.
`/var/log/syslog` now has entries that describe what goes on a bit:

```
Jan 21 22:10:13 bogo dnsmasq[28993]: vorgelagerte Server von DBus gesetzt
Jan 21 22:10:13 bogo dnsmasq[28993]: Benutze Namensserver 192.168.3.3#53
```

But that's - in my eyes - not really a satisfying solution, especially when something goes wrong.

Answer (score 1):

There is mention of one of the changes in the Networking stanza of the Quantal release notes.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/QuantalQuetzal/ReleaseNotes/UbuntuDesktop

The information that was formerly in /var/run/nm-dns-dnsmasq.conf is no longer in a file, but you can extract information using nmcli or nm-tool as has been described in other answers such as

[How to know what DNS am I using in Ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/197036/how-to-know-what-dns-am-i-using-in-ubuntu-12-04)

Comment: It only says that 127.0.1.1 is used now, not that `dnsmasq.conf` is empty.