# Do I need NetworkManager on Ubuntu Server?

Tags: networking, server, network-manager

I've seen several posts suggesting using `nmcli`, `nm-tool` and similarly named utilities for network related tasks.  In my case, I was trying to see what DNS my Ubuntu server installation is trying to use since my DNS lookup started failing after switching to static ip.

Here are some of the posts that mention these tools:

- [What is my DNS server?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/270479/what-is-my-dns-server#285878)
- [Command-line to list DNS servers used by my system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/152593/command-line-to-list-dns-servers#152610) (Answer 152610)
- [Command-line to list DNS servers used by my system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/152593/command-line-to-list-dns-servers#152611) (Answer 152611)

All of these assume that the `nm` tools are available on all systems, yet they're not on mine.  Apparently they are part of `NetworkManager`.  I haven't found network management on my server particularly difficult out of the box, but perhaps I'm missing something.  Should I install NetworkManager?

Here's my Ubuntu server version information:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.10
Release:    12.10
Codename:   quantal
```

Comment: If network-manager is not available you're probably not running stock Ubuntu.  Afaik, it is a default install.  You don't have to install it if you fix your dnsmasq configuration.

Comment: I'd try to avoid network manager if possible. If you are not using dnsmasq, the DNS servers are configured in /etc/resolv.conf - since you use static IP, I'd try to simply set them in that file and hope that it isn't overwritten on reboot... If it is overwritten I'd check if dnsmasq is being run at boot, and if it is, disable it.

Comment: @call me V: Networkmanager is pulled in, if you install gnome. It is not part of Ubuntu Server edition.

Comment: Don't disable dnsmasq, just learn to use it.  It builds the configuration it uses to overwrite with several config files.  Just use it properly instead of fighting with it. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dnsmasq

Comment: What would be the advantage of using dnsmasq on a server? I just see added complexity for very little gain...

Comment: It's the future.  You can fight it every release, or just learn to use it.

Comment: @CallmeV: Definitely stock Ubuntu, but the server addition, no GUI at all.

Comment: Thanks for all the discussion.  As to my DNS issue, it turned out that I simply had to add `dns-nameservers` to my `/etc/network/interfaces` file.